# Function list not appearing in BI Publisher when adding event triggers

Tags: bi-publisher, event-triggers

I'm trying to create an after-report trigger for my data model. I created the following package on my database:

**Package:**

```
create or replace PACKAGE CM_BILL_PRINT_PACKAGE AS 
   P_TO_ACCT_ID    CI_ACCT.ACCT_ID%TYPE;
   P_FROM_ACCT_ID  CI_ACCT.ACCT_ID%TYPE;
   P_BATCH_NBR     CI_BILL_ROUTING.BATCH_NBR%TYPE;
   P_BATCH_CD      CI_BATCH_CTRL.BATCH_CD%TYPE;
   P_LARGE_SW      CHAR(1);
   FUNCTION afterreport RETURN NUMBER;
END CM_BILL_PRINT_PACKAGE;
```

**Package Body:**

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY CM_BILL_PRINT_PACKAGE AS
   v_result NUMBER;
   FUNCTION afterreport RETURN NUMBER AS
      BEGIN 
         SELECT 1 INTO v_result FROM DUAL;
         RETURN (v_result);
      END afterreport;
END CM_BILL_PRINT_PACKAGE;
```

Afterwards I created provided the package name as my default DB package on the data model properties.

[Oracle DB Default Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1atyE.png)

Then proceeded to create the event trigger. However, the function I created does not appear on the list.

[Available Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFuIw.png)

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The RETURN type of Function should be of BOOLEAN type.
It will work.